# Can't print the check with php

Tags: php, sql-update

I have an issue with the printing of some subjects. This issue is the reason why I cant update my users information. Although this code is the right one I think.

Here is my code on the editprofile page.

```
include_once ("classes/Db.class.php");
include_once ("classes/config.class.php");
include_once ("classes/user.class.php");

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
    echo("not set");
    header("Location:index.php");
}
if (!empty($_POST['update'])) {
    echo "test 2";
    // todo: 1 form input velden ophalen
    try {
        $u = new User();
        $u->Username = $_POST['form-username'];
        $u->Email = $_POST['form-email'];
        $u->Password = $_POST['form-password'];
        $u->Passwordconfirmation = $_POST['form-passwordconf'];
        $u->Update($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        $u->profileImg($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        $succes = "Je gegevens zijn aangepast";
    } catch (exception $e) {
        $succes = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And here is the code in my user.class.php. and the specific function I wanted to talk to is the update function.

```
<?php
/**
* Created by PhpStorm.
* User: erhanlammar
* Date: 23/04/16
* Time: 10:13
*/

include_once("Db.class.php");

class User{

// todo: 1 private variabelen aanmaken voor firstname, lastname, ...
private $_db;
private $m_sUsername;
private $m_sFirstname;
private $m_sLastname;
private $m_sEmail;
private $m_sPassword;
private $m_sPasswordconfirmation;

private $m_sProfileimage;
//private $m_susersid;

// todo: 2 getters & setters!

public function __set($p_sProperty, $p_vValue){
    switch($p_sProperty){
        case "Username":
            if(!empty($p_vValue)){
                $this->m_sUsername = $p_vValue;
                break;
            }else{
                //opvangen van leeg veld username.
                throw new exception("vergeet geen username in te vullen");
            }
        case "Firstname":
            if(!empty($p_vValue)){
                $this->m_sFirstname = $p_vValue;
                break;
            }else{
                //opvangen van leeg veld firstname.
                throw new exception("Uw voornaam hebben we echt wel nodig");
            }
        case "Lastname":
            if(!empty($p_vValue)){
                $this->m_sLastname = $p_vValue;
                break;
            }else{
                //opvangen van leeg veld lastname.
                throw new exception("Heeft u geen achternaam?");
            }
        case "Email":
            if(!empty($p_vValue)){
                $this->m_sEmail = $p_vValue;
                break;
            }else{
                //opvangen van leeg veld email.
                throw new exception("Wij hebben uw email nodig om u op de hoogte te houden");
            }
        case "Password":
            if(!empty($p_vValue)){
                $this->m_sPassword = $p_vValue;
                break;
            }else{
                //opvangen van leeg veld firstname.
                throw new exception("Zonder wachtwoord geen login");
            }
        case "Passwordconfirmation":
            if(!empty($p_vValue)){
                $this->m_sPasswordconfirmation = $p_vValue;
                break;
            }else{
                //opvangen van leeg veld firstname.
                throw new exception("Zonder wachtwoord geen login");
            }
        case "Profileimage":
                $this->m_sProfileimage = $p_vValue;
                break;
    }
}
public function __get($p_sProperty){
    switch($p_sProperty){
        case "Username":
            return $this->m_sUsername;
            break;
        case "Firstname":
            return $this->m_sFirstname;
            break;
        case "Lastname":
            return $this->m_sLastname;
            break;
        case "Email":
            return $this->m_sEmail;
            break;
        case "Password":
            return $this->m_sPassword;
            break;
        case "Passwordconfirmation":
            return $this->m_sPasswordconfirmation;
            break;
        case "Profileimage":
            return $this->m_sProfileimage;
            break;
        }
}

private function checkPasswordConfirmation(){
    if($this->m_sPassword == $this->m_sPasswordconfirmation){
        return true;
    }else{
        throw new exception("wachtwoorden komen niet overeen");
    }
}


public function signup(){
    if(!$this->checkEmail()){
        throw new exception("Dit emailadres bestaat al neem een ander of ga naar login");
    }
    if(!$this->checkUsername()){
        throw new exception("De username die u gekozen heeft bestaat al!!");
    }
    if(!$this->checkPasswordConfirmation()){
        throw new exception("De registratie is niet correct verlopen. Check alles nog eens");
    }
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=IMDstagram", "root","");
    $options= ['cost' => 12];
    $this->m_sPassword = password_hash($this->m_sPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);
    $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(
      username,
      firstname,
      lastname,
      email,
      password
      )
      VALUES(
      :username,
      :firstname,
      :lastname,
      :email,
      :password
      )
      ");
    $statement->bindValue(":username", $this->m_sUsername);
    $statement->bindValue(":firstname", $this->m_sFirstname);
    $statement->bindValue(":lastname", $this->m_sLastname);
    $statement->bindValue(":email", $this->m_sEmail);
    $statement->bindValue(":password", $this->m_sPassword);
    return $statement->execute();

}

public function checkEmail(){

    $PDO = Db::getInstance();
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= :email");
    $stmt->bindValue(":email", $this->m_sEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ){
        return false;
        throw new exception( "" ) ;
    }
    else{

        return true;

    }
}
public function checkUsername(){

    $PDO = Db::getInstance();
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= :username");
    $stmt->bindValue(":username", $this->m_sUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ){
        return false;
        throw new exception( "" ) ;
    }
    else{
        return true;

    }
}

public function loggingIn(){
    if(!empty($this->m_sUsername) && !empty($this->m_sPassword)){
        $PDO = Db::getInstance();
        $stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
        $stmt->bindValue(":username", $this->m_sUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $password = $this->m_sPassword;
            $hash = $result['password'];

            if(password_verify($password, $hash)){
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $result['usersid'];
                $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $result ['username'];
                session_write_close();
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public function Update($userid){

    $PDO = Db::getInstance();

    if(!empty($this->m_sUsername)){

        $stmt = $PDO->prepare("UPDATE users SET username= :username  WHERE usersid = :usersid");
        $stmt->bindValue(":usersid", $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT );//update velden velden met where m_sUserid = Userid
        $stmt->bindValue(":username", $this->m_sUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo("username");

    }

    if (!empty($this->m_sEmail)){

        if(!$this->checkEmail()){
            throw new exception("De update is niet correct verlopen. Check alles nog eens");
        }

        $stmt = $PDO->prepare("UPDATE users SET email= :email WHERE usersid = :usersid");
        $stmt->bindValue(":usersid", $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT );//update username met " " "
        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $this->m_sEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR); //aleen email
        $stmt->execute();
        echo("email");

    }
    if (!empty($this->m_sPassword)){

        if(!$this->checkPasswordConfirmation()){
            throw new exception("de update lukt niet, passwoorden komen niet overeen.");
        }

        $stmt = $PDO->prepare("UPDATE users Set password = :password WHERE usersid = :usersid");
        $stmt->bindValue(":usersid", $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT );//update password met " " "
        $stmt->bindValue(":password", $this->m_sPassword, PDO::PARAM_STR); //aleen u password
        $stmt->execute();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Check whether the following instance properties `$m_sUsername`, `$m_sEmail` and `$m_sPassword` exist and set or not. You have set different instance properties `$u->Username = ...`, `$u->Email = ...` etc. 2) Refactor your *update()* method, instead of three *if* blocks use only one *if* block to update all three fields. 3) Don't store password as a plain readable text, always do [salted password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) before inserting.

Comment: they're all set and exist. The password is also hashed.

Comment: Where did you set all these instance properties, `$m_sUsername`, `$m_sEmail` and `$m_sPassword`, and where did you hash the password? I don't see *the code* anywhere.

Comment: So in which *if* block of `update()` method you have problem? I can't see any critical issue here except 2 things, 1) You should use one *if* block to update all three fields 2) I don't see this statement `$options= ['cost' => 12]; $this->m_sPassword = password_hash($this->m_sPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);` in your `update()` method, which means you haven't hashed the password before updating.

Comment: the issue I have is that the echo "test 2"; won't show after I click the submit button for the update

First I'll check if the 2 things you told me will solve it.

Comment: If you don't see `test 2`, then something is wrong in your html form. Check that and make sure you have a `name` and `value` attributes in the input submit element and the `value` attribute is not empty, `<input type="submit" name="update" value="submit" />`.

Comment: Okay the echo is printed so that works. 
Now my update query doesn't seem to work

Comment: And what do you mean with one if block @RajdeepPaul. Can you show me how you would write it down?

Comment: I've given an answer below. Please test your application with the given code.

Comment: Thanks,

The function works the thing is now the update won't happen in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of updating `username`, `email` and `password` fields separately in three `if` blocks, use only one `if` block to update all three fields.

So your `update()` method should be like this:

```
public function Update($userid){

    $PDO = Db::getInstance();
    if(!empty($this->m_sUsername) && !empty($this->m_sEmail) && !empty($this->m_sPassword) && !empty($this->m_sPasswordconfirmation)){
        if($this->m_sPassword == $this->m_sPasswordconfirmation){
            $options= ['cost' => 12];
            $this->m_sPassword = password_hash($this->m_sPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options);

            $stmt = $PDO->prepare("UPDATE users SET username= :username, email = :email, password = :password WHERE usersid = :usersid");
            $stmt->bindValue(":usersid", $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT );
            $stmt->bindValue(":username", $this->m_sUsername, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":email", $this->m_sEmail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindValue(":password", $this->m_sPassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // success
                echo "succes";
            }else{
                // error
                echo "failure";
            }
        }else{
            // Mismatch password
            echo "mismatch password";
        }
    }else{
        // some values are not set
        echo "some values are not set";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, The function works the thing is now the update won't happen in my database

Comment: @Lammar_E Check the status of `$userid` inside `update()` method. Do `echo $userid;` inside `update()` method and see what you're getting.

Comment: When I do an echo on the userid the username of that id is echoed on the page I got this output =>Jacky (this is the userid) je aanpassingen zijn doorgevoerd

Comment: @Lammar_E So is *Jacky* the correct user id? Check this against the particular row of the table you want to update.

Comment: @Lammar_E See this statement `$stmt->bindValue(":usersid", $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT );`, you have bind the user id as integer. So change this thing first, it should be `$stmt->bindValue(":usersid", $userid, PDO::PARAM_STR);` and test your application again.

Comment: @Lammar_E *hmm*, paste your current `update()` method on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here. Also see the raw query, do `echo "UPDATE users SET username= '" . $this->m_sUsername . "', email = '" . $this->m_sEmail . "', password = '" . $this->m_sPassword . "' WHERE usersid = '" . $userid . "'";` inside your `update()` method and check whether it's correct or not.

Comment: this is the output with echo of the query 
Jacky UPDATE users SET username= 'Lafon', email = 'J.lafon@gmail.com', password = 'test' WHERE usersid = 'Jacky'

Comment: @Lammar_E *strange*, your code as well query seems fine. What is the message being display after running `Update()` method, is it *Je aanpassingen zijn doorgevoerd* or something else?

Comment: It is  _Je aanpassingen zijn doorgevoerd_

Comment: @Lammar_E *This is completely blowing my mind*, the `UPDATE` query is working correctly. Just for debugging, check all column names, put different username, email and password in your html form and run the application again.

Comment: I think I found the issue.
I just tried the query in phpmyadmin it's correct but my usersid is a number instead of a name. 

But I don't know how I have to change that.

Comment: And that's why the update does not happen after the update button is clicked

Comment: It has to speak to a number not to a name

Comment: @Lammar_E What do mean *usersid is a number instead of a name*? Your user id is *Jacky*, right?

Comment: @Lammar_E Okay, so *that* is the issue. *usersid* field is an integer. May be you have stored *username* in `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` variable, check that. You have to store user's id which is an integer to `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` variable so that you could pass this value to `Update()` method like this: `$u->Update($_SESSION['loggedIn']);`

Comment: @Lammar_E Also, based on this update this statement `$stmt->bindValue(":usersid", $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);` is correct, so fix this.

Comment: okay,
this is my loggedIn function http://pastebin.com/dnGENutc
I don't think  the userid is stored in this.

I'm sorry, I am not a php wonder my job is more based on design and php is something I don't understand quite well

Comment: @Lammar_E See these two statements `$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $result['usersid']; $_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $result ['username'];`. In your `loggingIn()` method, you're overwriting `$_SESSION["loggedIn"]` with `$username`. So delete this second line `$_SESSION["loggedIn"] = $result ['username'];` from your `loggingIn()` method. Now it should work fine.

Comment: @Lammar_E Here's the updated `loggingIn()` method, [http://pastebin.com/RXcz7MAS](http://pastebin.com/RXcz7MAS)

Comment: Deleted the second line but still got the output userid= jacky instead of the real userid

Comment: @Lammar_E do `echo $_SESSION["loggedIn"];`, what do you see?

Comment: this is the code I wrote in the user.class
http://pastebin.com/D31QTB71

and this is the code on the page where I created the edit form.
http://pastebin.com/SseEgThD

Comment: @Lammar_E Paste your login code(html and php) on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and give me it's link here.

Comment: My login page http://pastebin.com/PC4L8sw8
My login code in the user.class http://pastebin.com/rYJZy5BB

Comment: @Lammar_E I think I figured out this problem. Clear your browser cache i.e  delete your browser cookies. If you're using Mozilla browser, go to *options* -> *Privacy* and click on *remove individual cookies* and when the browser window opens, click on *Remove all* button. And then run your application again. Here's the snapshot, [http://imgur.com/icvqgTS](http://imgur.com/icvqgTS)

Comment: Yes that did the job.
Thanks a lot to help me you made my day

Comment: @Lammar_E Glad I could help. Have a nice day. *Cheers! :-)*

Comment: One more small question. Now after I'm logged in I want to print the username on the homepage but it shows the userid now. How can I fix that?

Comment: Here's an image that shows what I mean http://imgur.com/ukGBF1k
The 2 next to _welkom_ has to be the username @Rajdeep Paul

Comment: @Lammar_E There are two ways you can solve this probelm. Either store the username in separate session variable, like this `$_SESSION['username'] = $result['username'];` and use it in your code, or fetch the appropriate row from the table based on this user's id and display it.

Comment: and how can I fetch the row that I need?

Comment: @Lammar_E Change your `loggingIn()` method in this way, [http://pastebin.com/Gbp4RJXt](http://pastebin.com/Gbp4RJXt) and change your page with this code snippet, [http://pastebin.com/hSNVpQch](http://pastebin.com/hSNVpQch). And don't forget to clear the browser cache. One quick suggestion: don't mix `mysqli` and `PDO` in your code, though it will work but you should not do this.